# How do I reverse a number in java

Tags: java, integer

Can anyone explain to me how to reverse a number start with zero in java. I trying to reverse a number 025 but output is only 52. But output should be 520
explanation much appreciated.

Comment: please provide your code and what you tried so far

Comment: Numeric reversal, I think, is mostly a *string* operation...

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it output 520000? After all, 025 and 000025 are the same number.

Comment: What is "an integer with zero"?  I use positive integers for counting the number of sheep in my field.  I know what 25 sheep look like, but what would 025 sheep look like?

Comment: @Sutanu: I think you should leave here your original wording with *integer* - thus your question will remain useful for future readers with the same initial understanding. Please read my answer below, follow the link to Oracle tutorial and implement the solution on your own - thus you will fulfil the intention of StackOVerflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing types. "025" is not a *number*, it's a `String`. In a *number* you simply **cannot** distinguish between 25, 025, 0025, 00025, ... Implement your assignment as a *String operation*.

```
public String reverseString(String s) {
    // put your code here
}
```

You may find very useful the Oracle tutorial on Strings here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: This is *almost* a good answer IMO; but you need to deal with a negative sign.

Comment: @Bathsheba: my answer does not *prevent* dealing with negative sign - it is the part `//put your code here` where it may be implemented :)
However, until it is defined in the specification I would not be sure what the expected output should be. Should `"-025"` convert to `"-520"`, `"520-"` or is such an input not to be expected at all? :)

Comment: The Apache Commons `StringUtils` class has a `reverse` method.

Comment: No.  An important part of professional computer programming is knowing when to write your own method, and when to use one that somebody else has already written and tested.  This is a clear case of the latter.

Comment: Well, in  20 years of programming, I've seen loads and loads of programmers write methods for themselves that they shouldn't have.  I really believe that "don't re-invent the wheel" should be one of the first lessons that every programmer should learn.  What you're doing here is specifically instructing the OP to re-invent his own wheels, and the opposite lesson is what's needed here.

Comment: As an integer, the literal `025` is not the same as `25`. Integer literals starting with `0` are octal literals, and `025` (octal) is equal to  `21` (decimal).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No, what I am doing is navigating the OP how to understand his requirement. I believe that he is a beginner who is learning how to write the elementary algorithms. Even if you (almost) never write your own sorting, implementing your own version of bubble sort, heap sort, quick sort is an important part of the curriculum. In my Java classes I often let the students implement a simplified version of `ArrayList`, even if they will never do it in their professional life. Reversing a string is one of the task every programmer should do in the first or the second lesson.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right, however the fact that `025` is an *octal* literal, is completely irrelevant for the given problem: **reversing a number**.

Comment: I was specifically replying to your statement that _"In integer you simply cannot distinguish between 25, 025, 0025, 00025"_, which is not true for Java integers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But you are talking about **integer *literals***, not about integers per se. I was talking about *integers* in its general meaning. It's not the same. Anyway, I changed the wording of my answer to make it unambiguous.